# JOOQ Vs Hibernate behavior

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jooq

As we know `Hibernate` have a a very good feature [SaveOrUpdate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate%28java.lang.Object%29) when we pass any object to this method it know data would be `update` or new record will be added in database. Is this feature also available in `JOOQ` Or in my code i have to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jOOQ does the same. If you change the primary key of a record, then it will use `INSERT`, otherwise, it will use `UPDATE`.

As it is, when you read a record from the database, then calling `store()` will trigger an `UPDATE` as you'd expect. If you create a new record, then it will be `INSERT`ed.

With 2.6, it's a bit hard to clone a record and then ask jOOQ to update it (since cloning will set the primary key in a new instance, hence marking it as "new" -> insert).

Comment: No, I mean `store()` method does tha same as `saveOrUpdate()`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "firing Update()"?

Comment: i think firing Update() query

Comment: I already answered this in detail. Please read my answer again.

Comment: @subodh: In my opinion, Aaron's answer is already very clear. There's really nothing else to add. `store()` executes an `UPDATE` or `INSERT`, depending on whether the primary key information is available in that record. I suggest you read the [Javadoc on that method](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html#store()), and try 1-2 things yourself in addition (or prior) to your Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @subodh: I suggest you create a new question here on stack overflow, clearly explaining your problem (with a code example). The question (as it is now) has been well answered by Aaron. What you're saying is another question. If we continue discussing this, this will be very confusing to future visitors of this question.

Answer (score 1):

if you read a record from database and call record.store() you will have the same behavior of hibernate saveOrUpdate method, it's works perfectly!

But in the most of cases you will not read the record from the database, you will receive a record from a controller or a view for example, in this case the method record.store() does not update, it always insert even you have the id setted.

For now I am implementing my own saveOrUpdate, checking by the record id.

```
public int saveOrUpdate(Record record) {
    if(record.getId() != null) {
        return record.update();
    } 
    return record.store();    
}
```