# How to add a OrderBy in Jooq for a Routine?

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jooq

I am using below code

```
Transaction transaction = Transaction.current();
        SelectQuery<Record> selectQuery = transaction.selectQuery();
        selectQuery.addSelect(Folder.FOLDER.FOLDER_RSN, Routines.fFoldernumber(Folder.FOLDER.FOLDER_RSN).as("FolderNumber"),
                Folder.FOLDER.FOLDER_NAME, Folder.FOLDER.FOLDER_TYPE);
selectQuery.addFrom(FolderPeople.FOLDER_PEOPLE);
```

Now i want to add OrderBy on `FolderNumber` Something like below

```
selectQuery.addOrderBy("FolderNumber")
```

How to add OrderBy in the above case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stored functions generated by jOOQ implement [`org.jooq.Field`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html), so you can simply add them to the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
selectQuery.addOrderBy(fFoldernumber(...));
```

Instead of repeating the whole call, you might also want to consider creating a local reference of your stored function call:

```
Field<?> folder = Routines.fFoldernumber(Folder.FOLDER.FOLDER_RSN).as("FolderNumber");
// ...
selectQuery.addSelect(..., folder);
selectQuery.addOrderBy(folder);
```

Comment: any update on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998470/jooq-vs-hibernate-behavior

Comment: @subodh: I think that Aaron has already sufficiently answered that question. I don't know what else to add.