# How to work with JOOQ store() Method?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

As i asked about a behavior of JOOQ [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998470/jooq-vs-hibernate-behavior) .@Aaron Digulla told me use store() method. But in my case i am using Transaction class do all delete,update,fetch operation.Something like this

```
        Transaction transaction = Transaction.current();
        int status = transaction.insert(myRecord);
```

But i want to do insert or Update based on record(If new then insert otherwise update) and  i got `store()` method handle this but `store()` work with record object.

```
        myRecord.store();
```

when i am doing this i am getting exception `No Connection configured`  its ok because this object not attached with any transaction . So in my case how to use `store()` method.Also one more question will it support batch `update` or `insert` with `store()` method?

```
Transaction is our own class where we used 
TransactionFactory.getCurrentTransaction()
public static Transaction getCurrentTransaction() {
        return threadLocal.get();
    }
```

And myRecord is a Object of the Record class which generated by JOOQ

Comment: Can you show us how you created `myRecord`? Also, what is `Transaction`? It is not part of the jOOQ API

Comment: Edited question with more code?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you just follow the [examples from the manual](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/simple-crud/) which explain how to create a new `UpdatableRecord` from a `Configuration` / `DSLContext` (in your case, this probably corresponds to whatever `Transaction` is:

```
DSLContext create = DSL.using(...);

// Create a new record
BookRecord book1 = create.newRecord(BOOK);

// Insert the record: INSERT INTO BOOK (TITLE) VALUES ('1984');
book1.setTitle("1984");
book1.store();

// Update the record: UPDATE BOOK SET PUBLISHED_IN = 1984 WHERE ID = [id]
book1.setPublishedIn(1948);
book1.store();
```

Notice the call to [`DSLContext.newRecord(Table)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#newRecord%28org.jooq.Table%29).

#### Batch storing

Please consider the Javadoc on [`DSLContext.batchStore()`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchStore%28java.util.Collection%29). Chances are, of course, that you might be able to check back with your coworker (I think?) here: [How to convert list into UpdatableRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20119215/521799)

Answer (score 0):

After five years, if you also use Java and jOOQ, you can try the version of 3.11.2 or latest.

There are something wrong of jOOQ in the versions of 3.10.6 ~ 3.11.1. You can find more infomation in [Regression in UpdatableRecord.store() and update() methods when used with connection pools](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7569).