# How to convert list into UpdatableRecord?

Tags: java, sql, database, jooq

I have issue related batchDelete in jooq. I have a list `folderProcessChecklistRecordList`in my code given below .But the issue is that  convert list into `UpdatableRecord` .Because of batchDelete argument required UpdatableRecord .

Error:

> The method batchDelete(UpdatableRecord...) in the type Transaction
>   is not applicable for the arguments
>   (List)

Code here:

```
public void deleteFolderProcessChecklist(String folderType, List<FolderProcessChecklistRecord> folderProcessChecklistRecordList) throws ProcessCheckListException{

        if(UserSubject.current().hasPermission(folderType, ButtonPermissionCode.FOLDER_PROCESS_CHECKLIST_DELETE)){
            Transaction.current().batchDelete(folderProcessChecklistRecordList));
        }else{
            throw new ProcessCheckListException();
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell me:

How to convert the list into updatablerecord ?

Comment: I am unsure if you should tag this as JDBC, although jooq might use JDBC, the problem has nothing to do with JDBC itself.

Comment: ok @MarkRotteveel i remove jdbc tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of potential problems here:

#### Your record simply isn't an `UpdatableRecord`

Are you sure that your `FolderProcessChecklistRecord` is an `UpdatableRecord`? Otherwise, you couldn't pass it to either `batchDelete()` method

#### Your `Transaction.current()` object doesn't implement all of `DSLContext`

jOOQ ships with overloaded `DSLContext.batchDelete()` methods:

- [`batchDelete(UpdatableRecord...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchDelete%28org.jooq.UpdatableRecord...%29)
- [`batchDelete(Collection<? extends UpdatableRecord<?>>)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#batchDelete%28java.util.Collection%29)

From [other questions (by your coworkers?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20116412/521799), I suspect that your custom `Transaction` type might not correctly implement `DSLContext`.

Comment: @S.SWAIN: Which one was it? I'm suspecting, the latter, right?