# What is the equivalent of hibernate's saveOrUpdate method in jooq?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jooq

I want to update row if it exists otherwise insert it. Is there any convenience method like hibernate's saveOrUpdate in jooq?

Currently i am checking in database if it exists then run update query otherwise insert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the different `UPSERT` statements supported by jOOQ, depending on your RDBMS:

- [`INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key/) as supported natively by MySQL. It can be emulated using both of the following options
- [`INSERT .. ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/insert-statement/insert-on-duplicate-key/) as supported natively by PostgreSQL. It can be emulated using the following option
- [`MERGE`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/merge-statement/) as supported natively by many RDBMS and the SQL standard

Comment: Thank you @Lukas for answering it. its working as expected. I must say Jooq is awesome.

Comment: @avisek1269: Thanks for the nice words! :)

Answer (score 0):

[From this Stack Overflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31973901/521799)

> if you read a **record** from database and call **record.store()** you will
>   have the same behavior of hibernate **saveOrUpdate** method, it's works
>   perfectly!
>
> But in the most of cases you will not read the record from the
>   database, you will receive a record from a controller or a view for
>   example, in this case the method **record.store()** does not update